# ERROR: syntax error at or near "case" Position: 226

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select 
       case when cld.last_milestone='APPROVED' THEN clf.application_received_and_approved_at
       case when cld.last_milestone='LOCK' THEN clf.locked_at
       case when cld.last_milestone='FUNDING' THEN clf.funded_at
       end as Last_Milestone_at
from
core.loan_file_milestone_days as clf
```

I CANNOT UNDERSTAND WHAT WENT WRONG HERE?

Comment: Usually it's `CASE .... WHEN .... THEN .... WHEN.... THEN .... WHEN .... THEN .... END` - you typically don't have to repeat the `CASE` .... a quick peek [at the official PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) would have told you so ....

Comment: Each Case need an end statement

Comment: @W_O_L_F: and a `,` at the end of the line - if those `case when` are indeed separate `case` expressions (separate "columns" in the result set)

Comment: case when cld.last_milestone='APPROVED' THEN clf.application_received_and_approved_at
       else case when cld.last_milestone='LOCK' THEN clf.locked_at
       else case when cld.last_milestone='FUNDING' THEN clf.funded_at
       end end end as Last_Milestone_at

Comment: I assume clf and cld is 2 different tables and you have now provided the join?

Answer (score 1):

Correct:

```
select 
   case
       when clf.last_milestone='APPROVED' THEN clf.application_received_and_approved_at
       when clf.last_milestone='LOCK' THEN clf.locked_at
       when clf.last_milestone='FUNDING' THEN clf.funded_at
   end as Last_Milestone_at
from
core.loan_file_milestone_days as clf
```

Comment: This is also causing the same issue
just need to use
case cld.last_milestone
when ' ' then
when ' ' then
end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select clf.loan_file_id,cld.last_milestone,
       case cld.last_milestone
       when 'APPROVED' THEN clf.application_received_and_approved_at
       when 'LOCK' THEN clf.locked_at
       when 'FUNDING' THEN clf.funded_at
       end as Last_Milestone_at
from
core.loan_files as clf
inner join
core.loan_file_milestone_days as cld
using(loan_file_id)
```

THIS IS THE SOLVED ONE
THANK YOU GUYS
Instead of using cld.last_milestone in condition again and again just go with
case cld.milestone
when condition then...
when condition then...
end as

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).